# Pull Values from a Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I am working on creating a user friendly character sheet for the new Pathfinder Playtest in Excel. I have run into an issue with a section and I have come here for help, not sure if it's the right place.

I want to have a cell return a value from a table (below) based on two other cell's values, e.g., if A1=19 and B1=4th it would pull the number from the appropriate area (3 in this case).

```
    1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th
1   2                               
2   3                               
3   3   2                           
4   3   3                           
5   3   3   2                       
6   3   3   3                       
7   3   3   3   2                   
8   3   3   3   3                   
9   3   3   3   3   2               
10  3   3   3   3   3               
11  3   3   3   3   3   2           
12  3   3   3   3   3   3           
13  3   3   3   3   3   3   2       
14  3   3   3   3   3   3   3       
15  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2   
16  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   
17  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2
18  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
19  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
20  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

I have tried using the below as well as just Indexing and I can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
=INDEX(P137:X156,MATCH(B2,O137:O156,1),MATCH(A10,P137:P156,1))
=INDEX(O137:O156,MATCH(1,(J125=P137:P156)*(J126=Q137:Q156)*(J127=R137:R156)*(J128=S137:S156)*(J129=T137:T156)*(J130=U137:U156)*(J131=V137:V156)*(J132=W137:W156)*(J133=X137:X156),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data starts at A1 like image below:

[image]

I Added 2 simple cells where user chooses the row and the column. Both cells use data validation lists related to your data, so no wrong info can be entered.

The formula is:

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576;MATCH($C$25;$A:$A;0);MATCH($C$26;$1:$1;0))
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

You can download the sample from Google Drive if you wish:

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QXFmmEPMtJeiHDjKKM0o6kclpMIzaw_i